# javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm making a website with lots of forms. I'm trying to make my codes efficient & flexible using Javascript form validation. I want to display error message next to each fields in the forms when not correctly entered.

Problems:
1. function "chkfrmRegister" is not working
2. elem.value IS working when "chkfrmRegister" is commented out.
3. cannot tab through fields when there's a field not correctly entered.
4. when submit, error messages doesn't appear next to the fields that wasn't correctly entered (guess it's because "chkfrmRegister" is not working that causes this)

Here is a test version of my codes:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="validate.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="frmRegister" method="post" action="">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label id="lFname" for="lFname">First Name*</label>
        <input id="iFname" name="iFname" class="text" size="38" maxlength="30" onblur="chkAlphabet(iFname, 'Please enter letters only')" />
      </li>
      <li><input id="iFnameMsg" class="errorStr" /></li>
      <li>
        <label id="lLname" for="lLname">Last Name*</label>
        <input id="iLname" name="iLname" class="text" size="38" maxlength="20" onblur="chkAlphabet(iLname, 'Please enter alphabets only')" />
      </li>
      <li><input id="iLnameMsg" class="errorStr" /></li>
      <li>
        <label id="lEmail" for="lEmail">Email*</label>
        <input id="iEmail" name="iEmail" class="text" size="38" maxlength="30" onblur="chkEmail(iEmail, 'Please enter a valid e-mail')" />
      </li>
      <li><input id="iEmailMsg" class="errorStr" /></li>
      <li>
        <label id="lContactNo" for="lContactNo">Contact No.*</label>
        <input id="iContactNo" name="iContactNo" class="text" size="38" maxlength="16" onblur="chkNumeric(iContactNo, 'Please enter numbers only')" />
      </li>
      <li><input id="iContactNoMsg" class="errorStr" /></li>
      <li><br />
      </li>
      <li>
        <!--<input type='submit' onclick="chkfrmRegister()" value='Register' />-->
        <input type='submit' value='Register' />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function chkfrmRegister(){
    var firstname = $("#iFname");
    var lastname = $("#iLname");
    var email = $("#iEmail");
    var contactno = $("#iContactNo");

    // Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
    if(chkAlphabet(firstname, "Please enter letters only")){
        if(chkAlphabet(lastname, "Please enter letters only")){
            if(chkEmail(email, "Please enter a valid email address")){
                if(chkNumeric(contactno, "Please enter numbers only. No space or special characters")){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;   
}

function chkAlphabet(elem, helperMsg){
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function chkNumeric(elem, helperMsg){
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function chkEmail(elem, helperMsg){
    var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
    if(elem.value.match(emailExp)){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Can someone please advise? Thanks!

Comment: `<label id="lFname" for="lFname">` — labels label form controls, not themselves. You should fix your `for` attributes.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is? What do you mean by "having trouble"? Are you getting a JS error? (Also, stylewise, I find those nested `if` statements a bit ugly: I'd either invert and test them one at a time like `if (!chkAlphabet()) return false;` (etc), or put them as one big condition: `if (chkAlphabet() && chkNumeric() && chkEmail()) { return true; }` - I can't show linebreaks in a comment, but put line breaks before or after each &&.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are beginning with this then its advisable for you to look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it has a form validation plugin which is very good.

here is an article on [jQuery form validation](http://webcloud.se/log/Form-validation-with-jQuery-from-scratch/)

Comment: Thanks Anantha. That's good reference. I can try using jQuery but would really like to know how I can fix the original codes that I posted up to learn the insights of JS.

Comment: Didn't work the old way after many tries so I tried jQuery plugin as you've suggested. Works well at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, you are trying to reinvent the wheel. There're lots of jQuery validation plugins that implement all the functionality you need. Plus, they give more user-friendly UI updates than you are trying to achieve - give the user chance to fill in the right values before showing errors. One of these validation plugins is [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). This is the one that ASP.NET MVC framework uses by default, and is definitely well developed and documented.

And if you still want to continue developing your code, the problem is in that you are using

```
elem.value
```

in your validation methods. `elem` is jQuery object and does not contain definition for `value`. Instead, in all of your validation functions, you should write

```
elem.val()
```

and your code will start working

Comment: I up-voted this comment, over the others, because it points to the package adopted by asp.net mvc.  You would have to figure that MS did the research and adopted the best package.

Comment: It is re-inventing the wheel, and I'd recommend using a plugin too, but still I can understand that the original poster might want to figure out why his or her existing code doesn't work before dumping it all to use a plugin. (Unfortunately they didn't actually say what their specific problem is.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried with elem.val() but it's still not working.
My idea is to pass info from HTML to JS -> validate each fields using JS -> display error messages/hints if necessary back on HTML. 
I can pass variables, etc. through HTML to JS (in other words, my original codes work) if I do not use "$(document).ready(function()" at the beginning of my JS but noticed that the validation behaves bit wierd...
I'm new to JS so can anyone please advise on this please?

Comment: This definitely works, i tested this on my machine and it works. Perhaps you failed to replace all of 'elem.value  '-s?

Comment: I've updated my codes and description on top. I've tested it and elem.value() works fine without "chkfrmRegister" function. What do you reckon I missed here?

Comment: instead of `elem.value.match` try `$(elem).val()`.. the object you are passing to the validate method is a jquery object & it usually won't work well with conventional javascript notation to access attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

You better try a `validationEngine` to resolve your problem~~~like[validationEngine](http://www.webappers.com/2009/06/12/jquery-inline-form-validation-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

There are great validation techniques out there for jquery; I would highly recommend one of those.

If you still prefer creating your own, you might want to apply some of these techniques.

- $('form').bind('submit', fncValidateSubmit) // hook onto the submit function
- fncValidateSubmit

  - make sure you check an attribute on the form to see if validation should take place, this way it can be switched off
  - $(this).filter('input... other elements').each(fncValidate);  // validate all the editable elements
- fncValidate()

  - $(this).attr('validationType');    // include the val type as an attribute when you render the element
  - // validate the element based on the type and add a label element dynamically next to the element that fails validation

    - return false as soon as one fails

Then you just need to create validation rules for each type; you should also include customValidation so the programmer can add their own regex validation.

If you want more features, you can slowly add them in... but at that point, you might as well use one of the pre-made packages.